# RDP into local server from 2 clients

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop

I am trying to setup a local machine with 2 nics that runs windows 7. The machine will not be connected to the internet. I would like to hardwire 2 ethernet connections into the device for 2 users to separately RDP into the machine for separate sessions. The machine will be used as a test enviroment. The two client machines will have dual nics. One for internet the other connected to the local server. Is this a plausible setup and how would I need to configure the RDP sessions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually with client releases of Microsoft Windows, they only allow one RDP connection at a time.  See http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/how-to-enable-concurrent-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows.html

I use Windows as my client and Ubuntu as my server.  I run VNC server on Ubuntu, which allows up to 10 clients under the free license.  Also, it is not encrypted, but on a LAN that shouldn't matter.

Check out https://www.realvnc.com/products/open/4.1/winvnc.html for more info on VNC.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Did the answer that I provided solve your dilemma?  If so, please mark my answer as correct by clicking on the check-mark below the up-down vote buttons.